# Given $\pi$ permutation on $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$, what is the sign of a permutation of $\{2,\dotsc,\hat\jmath,\dotsc,n\}$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, permutations

This question is related to my other question [Sign of the permutation which brings a subsequence back to its original form](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424340/sign-of-the-permutation-which-brings-a-subsequence-back-to-its-original-form). Suppose I have a complete ordered set $\{a_{1},\dotsc,a_{2n}\}$ and take $\pi$ to be a permutation of $\{1,\dotsc,2n\}$ such that $a_{\pi(1)}\le a_{\pi(2)}\le \dotsb \le a_{\pi(2n)}$. If we throw away the element $a_{1}$ and some other element, say, $a_{j}$, we end up with a complete ordered set which has now $2n-2$ elements. Suppose $\pi'$ is the permutation which brings it to an increasing order again, that is $a_{\pi'(2)}\le a_{\pi'(3)}\le\dotsb \le a_{\pi'(2n-2)}$. What is the relation between the sign of $\pi$ and the sign of $\pi'$?

Comment: I don't understand your notation.  Shouldn't the last entry in $a_{\pi'(2)} \le a_{\pi'(3)} \le \dotsb \le a_{\pi'(2n - 2)}$ be $a_{\pi'(2n)}$, and only $a_{\pi'(1)}$ and $a_{\pi'(j)}$ are missing from the list?

Comment: @LSpice yes, but since I eliminated $a_{1}$ and $a_{j}$, the set has now $2n-2$ elements. This is what I meant to write. For instance, if $a_{1} \le a_{4} \le a_{3}\le a_{2} \le a_{5}$ is the original ordered set and I eliminate $a_{1}$ and $a_{3}$, the new permutation $\pi'$ will lead to $a_{4} \le a_{2} \le a_{5}$.

Comment: I guess you don't mean $5$, since you wrote $2n$ … or maybe you wanted $n = 5/2$?  But, anyway, note that you have [written](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424447/given-pi-permutation-on-1-n-what-is-the-sign-of-a-permutation-of#comment1091001_424447) $a_4 \le a_2 \le a_5$, not $a_4 \le a_2 \le a_3$.  That is, the final index is still $2n$ (unless you choose to throw away the ($j = 2n$)th element itself), not $2n - 2$, even though there are only $2n - 2$ terms in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\sgn{sgn}$This is almost the same as your previous question, just with the order of the operations switched—whether you think of $\pi$ as ordering or disordering is just a matter of taking the inverse.

You previously needed $\pi^{-1}(1) - 1$ transpositions to bring the element $a_1$ to its new position $a_{\pi(\pi^{-1}(1))}$.  Instead, simply throw away $a_1$.  Separately, you would have needed $\lvert\pi^{-1}(j) - j\rvert$ transpositions to bring the element $a_j$ to its new position $a_{\pi(\pi^{-1}(j))}$.  This is unaffected by throwing away $a_1$, unless $\pi^{-1}(j)$ equals $1$, in which case it should be reduced by $1$.  Thus, throwing away both $a_1$ and $a_j$ gives you a new permutation $\pi'$ whose sign is $\sgn(\pi') = \sgn(\pi)\cdot(-1)^{(\pi^{-1}(1) - 1) + \lvert\pi^{-1}(j) - j\rvert}$ unless $\pi^{-1}(j) = 1$, in which case it is $\sgn(\pi') = \sgn(\pi)\cdot(-1)^{\pi^{-1}(1) + \lvert\pi^{-1}(j) - j\rvert}$.

Comment: LSpice, thanks again. I am trying to understand the machinery. Suppose $\pi(a_{1},...,a_{2n})$ is the sign of $\pi$. If $a_{1}$ is taken to position $p$ is it true that  $\pi(a_{2},...,a_{2n}) =(-1)^{p-1}\pi(a_{1},...,a_{2n})$ and further if $a_{j}$ goes to position $m$ then $\pi(a_{2},...,\hat{a}_{j},...a_{2n}) = (-1)^{|m-j|-1}\pi(a_{2},...,a_{2n})$?

Comment: I think the proposed sign notation runs the risk of confusion; but, with [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424447/given-pi-permutation-on-1-dotsc-n-what-is-the-sign-of-a-permutation-o/424449#comment1091055_424449) notation, yes, $p = \pi^{-1}(1)$ and $\pi(a_2, \dotsc, a_{2n}) = (-1)^{p - 1}\pi(a_1, \dotsc, a_{2n})$.  For your other equality, $m$ (position in the original list) is $\pi^{-1}(j)$, and the exponent is either $\lvert m - j\rvert - 1$ or $\lvert m - j\rvert$ according as $m = \pi^{-1}(j)$ does or does not equal $1$.

Comment: LSpice, right. And if $m$ is the position in the second list, when $a_{1}$ is erased already, does the result change?

Comment: Because then it seems that $m$ cannot be one.

Comment: Yes, the result changes according to whether $m = \pi^{-1}(j)$ is or is not $1$.